# getting each character in seperate line (each char is going to new line)while parsing a pdf file using apache tika

Tags: apache-tika

I am trying to parse a pdf file using Tika.When I parse my pdf file I am getting each character in separate line.For example my pdf file content is "Hello World".I am expecting to get the out like "Hello World",but I am getting output as follows.

```
H
e
l
l
o

W
o
r
l
d.
```

please help me to solve this issue.Following is my program.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;

public class TikaTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TikaTest test = new TikaTest();
        System.out.println(test.getContent());
    }

    public String getContent() {
        String content = "";
        Metadata mData = null;
        ContentHandler cHandler = null;
        AutoDetectParser adp = null;

        try {

            InputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                    "/home/prasad/Desktop/kc/Purchase Order Detail - TEXT.pdf"));
            mData = new Metadata();
            cHandler = new BodyContentHandler();
            adp = new AutoDetectParser();
            DefaultParser pdfParser = new DefaultParser();
            adp.parse(inStream, cHandler, mData);

            content = cHandler.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;
    }

}
```

I tried the solution given @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/27551264/4579100 
but still getting the same output.

Comment: What version of Apache Tika are you using? And if it isn't the newest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: PDF can deliver every character separately (self made kerning). Then spatial information must be used. Did not use Tika myself.

Comment: Hi @Gagravarr ,I am using tika-app-1.13.jar

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override characters method in BodyContentHandler and add new line character after each character

```
@Override
public void characters(char[] arg0, int arg1, int arg2) throws SAXException {

    if(arg0.length!=1)
    {
        char[] arr=new char[arg0.length*2];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i+=2)
        {
            arr[i]=arg0[i/2];
            arr[i+1]='\n';

        }
        super.characters(arr,arg1, arr.length);
    }
    else
    {
        super.characters(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi aravinth,thank you so much for your prompt responce.I tried with your code also but it doesn't work for me.Because for each "arg0" I am getting new character .If I get whole word as "arg0" and if it contains newline char between each character then your solution will work I think.But ,as I am getting single character per call, I am not able to solve the issue.Can you please give me any idea?.

Comment: Just add check for a single character inside this method

Comment: Hi aravinth,I didn't get your answer,can you tell me, how to do that?

Comment: I have modified with single character check